# Bootstrap dropdown list not expanding

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap dropdownlist is not displaying its list of contents on click. I added jquery library prior to the  bootstrap.min.js(This was the solution that i found in stack overflow,but it does not work for me).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div class="container features">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12"> 
    <div class="signin-div">
<h3 class="feature-title">Login Here..</h3>
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- Basic dropdown -->
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<!-- Basic dropdown -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use only one jQuery library. Also don't use slim.js

Comment: Now i removed slim.js.but no change

Comment: Also removed another jQuery library?

Comment: ya i removed the another library also

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

I have added popper.js before boostrap.js

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" i crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.0.4/popper.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div class="container features">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12"> 
    <div class="signin-div">
<h3 class="feature-title">Login Here..</h3>
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- Basic dropdown -->
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<!-- Basic dropdown -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

## paste this code in head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

## paste this code in body

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Glad to help you